# How can we know How many fingerprints are registered in an android device programatically..so as to allow only selected fingerprints inside an app

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, biometrics

Is there a way to know how many Fingerprints(FPs) are enrolled in an Android Device?..The motto here is to allow specific Fingerprint to enter an Application..while in the current scenario every FP enrolled in the device can enter the App..
Ex:- lets say we have 5 enrolled FPs stored in the android device..out of which the user can select only one or two according to his need and wish..while the remaining FPs will be not allowed to enter into the App..this will work like applock which will allow only user selected FPs to enter the app..
Is there any other way around??

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to know how many Fingerprints(FPs) are enrolled in an Android Device?

No.

> lets say we have 5 enrolled FPs stored in the android device..out of which the user can select only one or two according to his need and wish..while the remaining FPs will be not allowed to enter into the App

That is also not possible.

Comment: Is there any other way to get around it..

Comment: @Sandeep: Hopefully not, at least with built-in Android biometrics. That would indicate a major privacy and security flaw in Android. You are welcome to try to find and use a third-party external fingerprint reader.